# Problem with $lookup in a empty array in MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Have a great day wishes! I am using $lookup to join collection for processing but I am facing a problem with the output.

First of all I unwind the elements inside `followers` field to lookup and then I will set result lookup for a new field is `userInfo` but for the case of empty followers still added which results in the output not what I expected. Below are my actual steps:

Post collection:

```
 [
    {
       "_id": "648f6cac7f8ea20224715b0e",
       "name": "John Wicken",
       "text": "Hi there!",
       "createdAt": "2023-03-18T20:44:28.352Z",
       "followers": [
          "6497c6a35a1a1ca2ba7b9b51",
       ]
    },
    {
       "_id": "649a4a8c91f65a208b09d3a1",
       "name": "Ashley",
       "text": "Good morning!",
       "createdAt": "2023-06-27T02:34:39.514Z",
       "followers": []
    }
 ]
```

Aggregate Lookup pipeline stage:

```
     //  unwind to flatten followers for lookup each id element
     {
         $unwind: {
            path: '$followers',
            preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true
         }
     },

     //  join to users model
     {
         $lookup: {
             from: 'users', 
             localField: 'followers',
             foreignField: '_id',  // this _id is user id in users model              
             as: 'followers.userInfo',
         },
     },

     //  rewind unwind stage by user _id
     {
        $group: {
           _id: '$_id', // group by the _id of the Post collection
          rootDoc: {
             $first: '$$ROOT'
          },              
        }
     },

     //  replace root to get desired result
     { $replaceRoot: {...} }
```

Result:

```
 [
    {
       "_id": "648f6cac7f8ea20224715b0e",
       "name": "John Wicken",
       "text": "Hi there!",
       "createdAt": "2023-03-18T20:44:28.352Z",
       "followers": [
          { userInfo: {...} }
       ]
    },
    {
       "_id": "649a4a8c91f65a208b09d3a1",
       "name": "Ashley",
       "text": "Good morning!",
       "createdAt": "2023-06-27T02:34:39.514Z",
       "followers": [ // this field should be an empty array
          { userInfo: {} }
       ]
    }
 ]
```

In the result I got above, `followers` field from second element must be an empty array if it doesn't have any elements but it already persists `{ userInfo: {} }` inside, so I will refer to my question above again is there any way I can set condition to excute `$lookup` if `followers` field is not empty array to get the desired result?